# Android Mediaplayer error 2005

Tags: android

I'm getting a strange error code while trying to play video.

I get error code 1 (Which is ERROR_ UNKNOWN) and extra -2005 which has no documentation at all.

How can I possibly know why is this happening?

Thanks

```
01-09 09:50:36.903: E/MediaPlayer(3062): Error (1,-2005)
```

Here is the part when I play the video

```
if(m_videoView.canSeekForward() && seekTo > 0 && seekTo <= m_videoView.getDuration())
                    m_videoView.seekTo(seekTo);
                m_videoView.start();
                m_videoView.requestFocus();
                m_videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

Here is where I get the url for playing

```
String url = data.replace('\"', ' ').trim();
                        try
                        {
                            URL _url = new URL(url);
                            _url.toURI();
                        }
                        catch(URISyntaxException ex)
                        {
                            Log.e("url from media", ex.getMessage() + " for " + url);
                            SystemUtils.alertMsg(getContext(), "There is a problem with this film right now.\nPlease try again later.");//getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.not_subscribed_msg));
                            dismiss(); 
                            playerLayout.findViewWithTag("progressbar").setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return;  
                        } 
                        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                        {
                            Log.e("url from media", e.getMessage() + " for " + url);
                            SystemUtils.alertMsg(getContext(), "There is a problem with this film right now.\nPlease try again later.");//getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.not_subscribed_msg));
                            dismiss();
                            playerLayout.findViewWithTag("progressbar").setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return;
                        }

                        url = url.replace("http", "widevine").replace("16.109", "16.1");  

                        setFilePath(url);
```

Comment: Could you post your code please ?

Comment: It's a pretty massive code interacting with my server, requiring drm etc. What part of it is necessary?

Comment: The part that you are trying to play video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-2005` error code is likely to be `ERROR_DRM_DECRYPT` (see http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h#54) on ICS and later.

**EDIT**: It could also be `DRM_ERROR_CANNOT_HANDLE` if you're on Gingerbread or earlier.

Comment: Thank you. I'm running android 4.2 so probably the first option. But what does it actually mean?

Comment: Don't know. The code only says that that error code might be returned if there's an error in `decrypt`/`onDecrypt`, but doesn't say under which specific condition that would happen. I suppose it's implementation specific (i.e. depends on the DRM engine used).